# Accessing section or subsection

Tags: cross-referencing, sectioning

To access a section (or subsection), should I always put a `\label` after that section or is there any way to access that specific section without using `\ref` in another place?

Comment: This question is not very clear. Can you give an example of what you'd like to be able to write, showing why the usual `\label` and `\ref` don't work in your case.

Comment: Good question.  I think it would be clearer if *behind* were changed to *after*.

Comment: I'm sorry... But putting `\label` is just too much for me, since I have to put that everywhere... Well, if there's a simpler way, I would do the simpler one, wouldn't you? :)

Comment: @zfm: Can you please explain _how_ you want to "access that specific section"? Do you already have an idea how that could look like? (Another thing: There's no need telling such minor edits explicitly.)

Comment: just as usual.. putting `section{something}\label{here}` then doing `ref{here}` somewhere else... Since I write a lot of sections (and subsection), I am too lazy to write that `\label` in all sections...

Comment: @zfm: So how do you want to use `\ref{here}` then without the label? (Note that using "@Hendrik" in your comment will notify me.)

Comment: @Hendrik: that's the point of my question, since I don't want to put `\label` and `\ref`... I wonder if there is anything such as `\referSection{something}`... (I think this is the end of my explanation, since I now quite believe that the answer is _no_ )

Comment: @zfm: That's what I was trying to make you see for yourself -- success `:-)`

Comment: @zfm: What would happen if you have two sections of the same name (say in different chapters)?

Comment: @caramdir: no idea up until now... I think that's the drawback, but I don't really think of the drawback like that :)

Answer (score 6):

You need to use a `\label` **after**, not before, the sectioning, caption or other command you want to reference. You need to use `\label` and `\ref`, or similar commands, to access sections by label (name).

The `hyperref` package can create bookmark entries for the PDF without `\label`'s which also allow you to jump to chapters, sections, etc. but it will not allow you to reference this sections from other places in the text.

Comment: so there is a package `hyperref` where I can refer section without labelling everything? That's good.

Comment: It will create a ToC like bookmark collection, but you can not place references to certain sections in the text without `\label` or `\hypertarget` etc.

Comment: I think this answer would be clearer if *in front* and *behind* were changed to *before* and *after*.

Comment: @Matthew: Normally I would have used *before* and *after*, but the OP used *in front* and I wanted to match that. I changed it now. Thanks.

Comment: I hadn't noticed that.  I'll make the same suggestion to the question (which has a comment that "This question is not very clear")

Answer (score 3):

If you are seeking a method for referring to the *current* section number without using `\label` and `\ref`, then you could do the following

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{First Section}
\subsection{First SubSection}
This sentence appears in Section~\thesection, specifically,
in Subsection~\thesubsection.
\end{document}
```

Comment: this is good, though I think that referring current section or subsection is not really useful for me...